# android studio butterknife.compiler.ButterKnifeProcessor

Tags: java, android, sdk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW2uZ.png)Cause: superclass access check failed: class butterknife.compiler.ButterKnifeProcessor$RScanner (in unnamed module @0x4cf96f21) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.tree to unnamed module @0x4cf96f21

this error show when i run the apk and make build

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.